# A set theory problem involving four sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> In a battlefield, $70$% soldiers lost an eye, $80$% lost one leg , $85$% lost an ear and $90$% lost an arm. Then, atleast how many of them lost all the four organs ?

Here's what I tried. Let the total number of soldiers be 100 and set of people who lost their eye , leg , ear and arm be denoted by $A,B,C$ and $D$ respectively. Also , number of those who lost all four organs be $x$. Then,

$$x= 70+ 80+85+90-\sum_{cyclic} n(A\cap B)+\sum_{cyclic} n(A\cap B\cap C)- n(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)$$

It's not necessary that$ n(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)$ is 100 because there could be some soldiers who didn't lost any organs at all. I'm stucked here as there are two types of terms here who values are unknown  and Venn diagram is quite complex and not useful here. How can I minimise $x$ ?

Comment: You have $70\%+80\%+85\%+90\%$ is $4 \times \%$lost four $+ 3 \times \%$lost three  $+ 2 \times \%$lost two  $+ 1 \times \%$ lost one  $+ 0 \times \%$ lost zero, with the five percentages all being non-negative and adding up to $100\%$. You want "$\%$lost four" to be as small as possible, so this is a numerical optimisation problem with an intuitively simple solution

Comment: @Henry Thanks sir. But did you instead meant this by your first line :  $70$%$+80$%$+85$%$+90$%
 is $4×$%
lost exactly 1 $+6×$%
lost exactly two $ +4×$%
lost exactly two$ +1×$%
 lost exactly four$ +0×$%
 lost zero ?

Comment: No - I meant what I said: $70\%+80\%+85\%+90\% = 325\%$ and "lost four" is clearly minimised using $325\% = 4\times 25\%+3 \times 75\%+2 \times 0\% +1 \times 0\% +0 \times 0\% $ so at least $25\%$  lost all four.  If you had $3\times 100\%$, you would only have $300\%$ so obviously need to shift $25\%$ into "lost four" to reach $325\%$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a set $S$ of $100$ soldiers. Rather than looking at the sets of soldiers that have lost eyes, legs, ears, arms, let's look at the sets of soldiers that kept them. Let

\begin{align*}
I&:= \{\text{Soldiers in $S$ that kept both eyes}\} \\
L&:= \{\text{Soldiers in $S$ that kept both legs}\} \\
E&:= \{\text{Soldiers in $S$ that kept both ears}\} \\
A&:= \{\text{Soldiers in $S$ that kept both arms}\}.
\end{align*}

We know that $|I| = 30$, $|L| = 20$, $|E| = 15$ and $|A| = 10$. The set we are interested in, the set of people who lost all four organs, is given by:
$$S \setminus (I \cup L \cup E \cup A).$$
We want to minimise the cardinality of this set, which is equivalent to maximising the cardinality of $I \cup L \cup E \cup A$.

How do we maximise $|I \cup L \cup E \cup A|$? The four sets have a total of $30 + 20 + 15 + 10 = 75$. If any pair of the above sets intersect, then the union will contain fewer than $75$ elements. If we make it so that $I, L, E, A$ are pairwise disjoint, then we will have exactly $75$.

This number is possible too: imagine the soldiers are arranged in a row. If the first $30$ kept both their eyes, but lost a leg, ear, and arm, then the second $20$ kept both legs, but lost an eye, ear, arm, etc, then the first $75$ soldiers belong to $I \cup L \cup E \cup A$. This just means the inequality $|I \cup L \cup E \cup A| \le 75$ is sharp: $75$ is not just an upper bound, it is the maximum.

This implies the minimum value of
$$|S \setminus I \cup L \cup E \cup A| = 100 - |I \cup L \cup E \cup A|$$
must be $100 - 75 = 25$. That is, $25\%$ is the minimum percentage of soldiers who lost all four limbs.

Comment: *"If we want to minimise those that have lost all four organs, then we want these sub-populations to collectively cover the most ground, which we do by making them not overlap."* Sir , can you please explain this line more simply ? I think it's the main part of your answer but I can't understand it.

Comment: @An_Elephant I've tried a second pass at explaining this. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Thanks sir for the edit. I finally get it.